# Cloud Endpoints Framework Version 2 inconsistent and high unexplainable latency

Tags: google-app-engine-python, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I recently migrated my App from version 1 of Cloud Endpoints Frameworks to version 2 (App Engine python standard). Supposedly one of the benefits is reduced request latency. Ignoring warm up and/or starting the backend instance, it seems I was getting unexplained latency outside observable logs/app stats, of anywhere from 300ms to 2 seconds. After observing this for about a week I finally just went back to the echo example and deployed to a test app and noticed the exact same behavior.

Echo example: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/get-started-frameworks-python

Here is the relevant instance settings in my app.yaml:

```
runtime: python27
env: standard
threadsafe: true
instance_class: B2
basic_scaling:
    idle_timeout: 900s
    max_instances: 2
```

Here are 3 requests to the api via curl spaced multiple seconds apart. The test app should not be doing anything else:

```
MacBook-Pro$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"content":"hello world"}' https://testtictactoe-164905.appspot.com/_ah/api/echo/v1/echo -w "@curl-format.txt"
{
 "content": "hello world"
}
time_namelookup: 0.005
time_connect: 0.019
time_appconnect: 0.152
time_pretransfer: 0.152
time_redirect: 0.000
time_starttransfer: 0.263
--------
time_total: 0.263

MacBook-Pro$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"content":"hello world"}' https://testtictactoe-164905.appspot.com/_ah/api/echo/v1/echo -w "@curl-format.txt"
{
 "content": "hello world"
}
time_namelookup: 0.005
time_connect: 0.020
time_appconnect: 0.144
time_pretransfer: 0.144
time_redirect: 0.000
time_starttransfer: 0.613
--------
time_total: 0.613

MacBook-Pro$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"content":"hello world"}' https://testtictactoe-164905.appspot.com/_ah/api/echo/v1/echo -w "@curl-format.txt"
{
 "content": "hello world"
}
time_namelookup: 0.005
time_connect: 0.021
time_appconnect: 0.145
time_pretransfer: 0.145
time_redirect: 0.000
time_starttransfer: 1.028
--------
time_total: 1.028
```

Here is the app stats for the first 0.263 second request (Grand Total 48ms):
[image]
Here is part of the log entry for 0.263 second request:
[image]

Here is the app stats for the 1.028 second request (Grand Total 504ms):

[image: App stats for 1.028 second request]
Here is part of the log entry for the 1.028 second request
[image]

Here is the instance latency for the last hour:

[image]

1. Why is the actual latency of my request so much higher than what is shown by the logs and app stats?
2. Is this extra overhead latency of up to 600ms, which seems completely out of my control, just an expected part of making google cloud endpoints requests?
3. Why does this latency fluctuate so much when dealing with just one instance and very few incoming requests?

Comment: I'm not sure where you're getting "Supposedly one of the benefits is reduced request latency."
Endpoints v2 actually does more things (the API management features), so I would not expect reduced latency.

Comment: Got that from reading this link: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/legacy/v1/python/migrating First bullet point under benefits says "Reduced request latency"

Comment: Thanks; I'll double-check on that internally.

Comment: Can you please check if you see a warning like this in your logs? "no scheduler thread, scheduler.run() will be invoked by report"

Comment: I just fired off 10 curl commands to this interface which has not been exercised in a while, the first command did have a warning: no scheduler thread, scheduler.run() will be invoked by report(...). The subsequent 9 commands did not have this warning. The latency as reported by curl ranged from 2.148 seconds to 0.687 seconds. If you would like a full copy of my logs let me know.

Comment: The answer from @Codiak on this question: stackoverflow.com/questions/45585413/… helped latency immensely. I jettisoned API Managment completely and the majority of my fluctuating mystery latency went away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting rid of API management did the trick. I tried this based on the answer from @Codiak to this question: stackoverflow.com/questions/45585413/

Once I made this change latency was much more consistent and dramatically improved.

To accomplish this I basically removed these two lines from app.yaml:

ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_NAME:

ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_VERSION: 2018-05-05r0

I also removed [apiname]openapi.json from my project. This also means I no longer have to go through many of the steps described here:

1. https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/get-started-frameworks-python#deploy_configuration
2. https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/get-started-frameworks-python#deploy_backend

Answer (score 0):

Your application's performance problem is probably due to the API management functionality running on the request thread, instead of in a background thread. Try setting "threadsafe: true" in your app.yaml.

Comment: I had toggled threadsafe flag to see if it made a difference when I originally encountered the latency. I just put it back to threadsafe: true. 10 more commands to echo api all show about 200ms logs/trace but the actual round trip as reported by curl is still ranging from 600ms - 1 second. I still don't understand where 800ms of unexplained latency is coming from?

Comment: Perhaps I just need to set my expectations as follows when using google cloud endpoints: 0-200ms (time to connect), ~250ms (explained api handling code assuming no datastore, observable in trace/logs), 0-500ms (unexplained time + time to send the response back via http request) As the api becomes more complex and actually starts making datastore requests, the user should expect to experience a 1-2 second delay for each endpoints api request.